# I am making a AJAX request to the database but it makes numerous ajax request instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax request to the database which works fine but it inserts numerous entries which I do not want - I only want one entry per request. Please see my code below: When the ajax is submitted, the data values should only add once, but in my case the ajax fires more than once when i click the submit button. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

I am trying to make an ajax request to the database which works fine but it inserts numerous entries which I do not want - I only want one entry per request. Please see my code below: When the ajax is submitted, the data values should only add once, but in my case the ajax fires more than once when i click the submit button. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

If there is a better or easier way to do this I would be more than happy for suggestions. I thought this was happening because the ajax was within the foreach loop initially but I then moved it out of the loop and am having the same issues.

```
const formURL2 = `/wp-content/themes/tmm/includes/legacy/externalViewBMlog.php`;

_wq.push({
  id: "_all",
  onReady: function(video) {
    var hashed_ID = video.hashedId();
    let poll_start_time;
    let poll_end_time;
    var polling_container = $(".poll-container");
    var gui_ia_item_child;
    var gui_ia_item;
    var question_index = 1;
    var total_questions;
    var poll_wistia_parent_id;
    var gui_ia_poll;
    var answer_id;

    video.bind("secondchange", function(seconds) {
      polling_container.each(function() {
        poll_wistia_parent_id = $(this).data("wistia-parent-id");
        if (hashed_ID === poll_wistia_parent_id) {
          gui_ia_item_child = $(this).children().find("#gui-ia-item_" + poll_wistia_parent_id + "-" + question_index);
          gui_ia_item = gui_ia_item_child.parent();
          gui_ia_item.show();
          gui_ia_poll = gui_ia_item.next().find("form");
          total_questions = $(this).children(".gui-ia-items").length;

          gui_ia_item.on("click", function() {
            $(this).next().addClass("gui-ia-slideout-active");
          });

          poll_start_time = gui_ia_item_child.data("start-time");
          poll_end_time = gui_ia_item_child.data("end-time");

          if (seconds >= poll_start_time) {
            gui_ia_item_child.addClass("gui-ia-item-active");
            if (seconds >= poll_end_time) {
              gui_ia_item_child.removeClass("gui-ia-item-active");
              question_index++;
            }
          } else if (seconds <= poll_start_time) {
            gui_ia_item_child.removeClass("gui-ia-item-active");
            if (question_index > 1) {
              question_index--;
            }
          } else if (question_index > total_questions) {
            question_index = total_questions;
          }

          $(".gui-ia-slideout-close, .gui-ia-poll-results-container button.gui-ia-poll-close").on("click", function() {
            $(".gui-ia-slideout").removeClass("gui-ia-slideout-active");
          });

          gui_ia_poll.children(".gui-ia-poll-answer").on("click", function() {
            answer_id = $(this).data("vote");
            $(".gui-ia-slideout-inner .gui-ia-poll-result-container[data-vote=" + answer_id + "]").addClass("selected");
            $(".gui-ia-slideout-inner .gui-ia-poll-result-container[data-vote=" + answer_id + "]").siblings('[data-vote]').removeClass("selected");
            $(".gui-ia-poll-answers-container input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
          });

          gui_ia_poll.on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            $.ajax({
              url: formURL2,
              type: 'POST',
              data: {
                action: "interactivity_quiz",
                postId: 56753,
                videoId: 23457,
                quizId: 3,
                questionId: 2,
                answerId: answer_id
              },
              success: function() {
                console.log("form submitted");
                gui_ia_poll.parents(".gui-ia-slideout").addClass("gui-ia-poll-completed");
                gui_ia_item_child.addClass("gui-ia-complete gui-ia-item-active");
              },
              error: function() {
                console.log("Error with quiz form");
              }
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You're calling your ajax within `polling_container.each(function(){...`, so it's calling for each iteration of `polling_container`.

Comment: @mykaf They're not calling AJAX in the loop, they're adding an event listener in the loop.

Comment: You should bind your variables inside the innermost function. All your `success` functions share the same scope of `gui_ia_poll` and `gui_ia_item_child`, so they all add the class to the last one.

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: Make sure you're not binding handlers to the same element in the loop. If you are, it will make multiple AJAX calls when you submit it.

Comment: In order to prevent additional listeners from accumulating when the video event triggers many times, you must move the event binding code outside of the loop.

Comment: you are binding submit multiple times.... Every time `secondchange` is triggered you are binding new events to all those elments. They do not get written over.

Comment: The code is outside of the loop completely but still firing the AJAX function numerous times

Comment: Per your code here, your submit event is added within `polling_container.each(...`